# how to call webservice jsp

Tags: ios

1. I was developer iphone app. website is developed by php developer used phpMyAdmin database. i was used webservices retrive data from phpmyadmin database. successfully completed my app.
2. I have to develop on more app. that website is developed  by java developers and oracle database is used.
3. my question is how to interact oracle database how to retrive data and how to write webserices for iphone.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use Jersey Rest or Spring MVC for REST Service.

Here are the link -

jersey.java.net

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-tomcat/